# Mostrar mas de un resultado retrofit

Tags: php, mysql, android

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo que estoy usando para pruebas.

Mi codigo me realiza una busqueda en mi base de datos en la tabla `tb_image`, la busqueda la realiza mediante `id` y de esta manera me debe mostrar todos los registros que esten ligados con ese `ID`.

Lo que quiero que me ayuden es como puedo hacer que al realizar la consulta por `id` me muestre todos los registros y no solo uno pongo un ejemplo rapido de 20 registros que tengo en mi tabla 4 son con el id `1` entonces al realizar la consulta deberia mostrarme los 4 y no lo esta haciendo solo me muestra 1 ese es mi problema y no encuentro como arreglarlo.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etIdBuscar, etId, etNombre, etTelefono;
    Button btnIdBuscar, btnEliminar, btnTodosBuscar, btnAgregar, btnEditar;

    RecyclerView rvUsuarios;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    AdaptadorUsuarios adaptadorUsuarios;

    Retrofit retrofit;
    APIRest api;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        etIdBuscar = findViewById(R.id.etIdBuscar);
        etId = findViewById(R.id.etId);
        etNombre = findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
        etTelefono = findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
        btnIdBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnIdBuscar);
        btnTodosBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnTodosBuscar);
        rvUsuarios = findViewById(R.id.rvUsuarios);
        rvUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        retrofit = new AdaptadorRetrofit().getAdapter();
        api = retrofit.create(APIRest.class);

        getUsuarios(api);

        btnIdBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(etIdBuscar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserta un ID para buscar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    getUsuario(api, etIdBuscar.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        btnTodosBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getUsuarios(api);
            }
        });

    }

    public void getUsuario(final APIRest api, String idUsuario) {
        listaUsuarios.clear();
        Call<Usuario> call = api.obtenerUsuario(idUsuario);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
                switch (response.code()) {
                    case 200:
                        listaUsuarios.add(response.body());

                        etIdBuscar.setText("");

                        adaptadorUsuarios = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                        rvUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptadorUsuarios);

                        break;
                    case 204:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No existe ese registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        etIdBuscar.setText("");

                        getUsuarios(api);
                        break;
                        
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void getUsuarios(APIRest api) {
        listaUsuarios.clear();
        Call<List<Usuario>> call = api.obtenerUsuarios();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Usuario>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Response<List<Usuario>> response) {
                listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>(response.body());

                adaptadorUsuarios = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                rvUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptadorUsuarios);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

APIRest.java

```
public interface APIRest {

    @GET("API_REST.php")
    Call<List<Usuario>> obtenerUsuarios();

    @GET("API_REST.php")
    Call<Usuario> obtenerUsuario(
            @Query("idUsuario") String idUsuario
    );
}
```

Y asi tengo el PHP

API_REST.php

```
<?php
    require "conexion.php";
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
      
      // READ


      if(isset($_GET['idUsuario'])) {
        // http://localhost/PruebasCanal/API_REST.php
        $idUsuario = $_GET['idUsuario'];

        //Metodo de busqueda por ID
        $sql_select_id = "SELECT name, id_plan FROM tb_image WHERE id_plan='$idUsuario'";
        $query_select_id = $mysqli->query($sql_select_id);
        
        $filas = $query_select_id->num_rows;
        if($filas == 0) {
          //echo "No existe ese registro";
          header("HTTP/1.0 204");
        } else {
          $resultado = $query_select_id->fetch_assoc();
          echo json_encode($resultado);
        }
      } 
      
      else {

        //Metodo de busqueda general
        // http://localhost/PruebasCanal/API_REST.php?idUsuario=#
        $sql_select = "SELECT name, id_plan FROM tb_image";
        $query_select = $mysqli->query($sql_select);

        $datos = array();
        while($resultado = $query_select->fetch_assoc()) {
          $datos[] = $resultado;
        }

        echo json_encode($datos);
      }
    } 

?>
```

En el php ya intente jalar la informacion como con el general mediante un `WHILE` pero cuando lo hago ya no me muestra nada no me hace la busqueda.

Aqui realize la busqueda del ID `2` y solo me muestra esa fotografia pero aun hay 3 mas que no esta mostrando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe el archivo php directamente en mi navegador y efectivamente el problema lo tengo en el PHP.

Aqui me muestra que como resultado de la consulta y buscar todos los registros del `id = 1` me regresa solo 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutar la consulta como tal en sql me devuelva mas de 1 registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que este haciendo mal les agradeceria mucho la orientacion o la ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta está planteada de forma algo confusa. ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente y en qué parte del código? Pulsa en [edit] y clarifica tu planteamiento.

Comment: El problema es que al buscar por el ID deberia mostrarme todas las fotos que esten registradas con el id que ingrese te pongo un ejemplo tengo 4 fotos registradas con el id `1` este id es una foreign key entonces de esas 4 fotos solo me muestra una.

Comment: Y lo que yo quiero es que me muestre las 4 en vez de 1

Comment: No se si ya es un poco mas entendible mi pregunta

Comment: Ya, pero, ¿qué es lo que no funciona, el código PHP o el código Java? Es decir, ¿verificaste por ejemplo que en PHP te trae todas las fotos?

Comment: Pon puntos de interrupción en tu código Java y verifica por dónde entra y qué valores tienen los objetos. Es el ABC de la depuración, que te va a ahorrar muuuuchas horas en el futuro. Es que no podemos saber, leyendo tu pregunta, qué condiciones se cumplen, si el código entra por `getUsuarios()` o por `getUsuario()`, o qué valores estás obteniendo en el `onResponse()`. Poniendo puntos de interrupción podrás verificar eso.

Comment: entra por getUsuario y solo me esta devolviendo una sola foto no me devuelve todas creo que mi problema esta en el Php por que solo me extrae la primera fila pero no se como cambiarlo para que me extraiga todas

Comment: Puse los puntos de interrupcion y obtuve lo siguiente en el modulo de **RUN**,             `I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2632 bytes, containing 1 windows, 15 views
W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored`

Comment: Y en **logcat** obtuve lo siguiente `Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored`

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo consegui deje mi respuesta por si a alguien le llega a servir

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etIdBuscar, etId, etNombre, etTelefono;
    Button btnIdBuscar, btnEliminar, btnTodosBuscar, btnAgregar, btnEditar;

    RecyclerView rvUsuarios;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    AdaptadorUsuarios adaptadorUsuarios;

    Retrofit retrofit;
    APIRest api;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        etIdBuscar = findViewById(R.id.etIdBuscar);
        etId = findViewById(R.id.etId);
        etNombre = findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
        etTelefono = findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
        btnIdBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnIdBuscar);
        btnTodosBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnTodosBuscar);
        rvUsuarios = findViewById(R.id.rvUsuarios);
        rvUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        retrofit = new AdaptadorRetrofit().getAdapter();
        api = retrofit.create(APIRest.class);

        btnIdBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(etIdBuscar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserta un ID para buscar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    getUsuario(api, etIdBuscar.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public void getUsuario(final APIRest api, String idUsuario) {
        listaUsuarios.clear();
        Call<List<Usuario>> call = api.obtenerUsuario(idUsuario);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Usuario>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Response<List<Usuario>> response) {

                        listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>(response.body());

                        etIdBuscar.setText("");

                        adaptadorUsuarios = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                        rvUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptadorUsuarios);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

APIRest.java

```
public interface APIRest {

    @GET("API_REST.php")
    Call<List<Usuario>> obtenerUsuario(
            @Query("idUsuario") String idUsuario
    );
}
```

AdaptadorRetrofit

```
public class AdaptadorRetrofit {

    Retrofit retrofit;

    public AdaptadorRetrofit(){ }

    public Retrofit getAdapter(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.100.71/PruebasCanal/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

AdaptadorUsuarios.java

```
public class AdaptadorUsuarios extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorUsuarios.UsuarioViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    public AdaptadorUsuarios(Context context, List<Usuario> listaUsuarios) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listaUsuarios = listaUsuarios;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsuarioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_usuario, null, false);
        return new AdaptadorUsuarios.UsuarioViewHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsuarioViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load("http://mi_ip/upload_file/RestApi/upload/"+listaUsuarios.get(position).getName()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.tvNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuarios.size();
    }

    public class UsuarioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNombre;

        ImageView imageView;

        public UsuarioViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            tvNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);

        }
    }
}
```

Y asi quedo mi clase php

API_REST.php

```
<?php
    require "conexion.php";
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
      
      // READ


      if(isset($_GET['idUsuario'])) {
        // http://localhost/PruebasCanal/API_REST.php
        $idUsuario = $_GET['idUsuario'];

        //Metodo de busqueda por ID
        $sql_select_id = "SELECT id_img,name, id_plan FROM tb_image WHERE id_plan='$idUsuario'";
        $query_select_id = $mysqli->query($sql_select_id);
        
        $datos = array();
        while($resultado = $query_select_id->fetch_assoc()) {
          $datos[] = $resultado;
        }

        echo json_encode($datos);
      } 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Pero, que es lo que realizaste, que cambio? ,, revisar [answer]-

Comment: buen dia lo que cambio fue el metodo obtener usuario y el php en ambos solo estaba extrayendo un solo registro en ves de todos en el metodo `obtenerusuario` lo que hice fue agregar todo lo encontrado por el php en la variable lista y en el php cree un while para mostrar todos los resultados en base al id enviado